# Can eBay work with your bank card

Tags: credit-card, banking, debit-card, deposits

I want to deposit 60$ I have in my eBay account from doing online surveys and such, but ebay only has my debit card number. Will my bank (Huntington) or any bank allow it to be deposited through my card number and not a direct deposit number? If so how would it work?

Comment: I don't believe e-bay is willing to transfer the funds this way, whether or not your bank would permit it.

Comment: Do you mean in your paypal account?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR;** - The feature exists, but is not universal. you have to check with paypal if you are eligible for it.

---

Long answer:

Assuming you mean PayPal, eBay virtual wallet subisidary and payment processor.

Also assuming your card is a multiple function card that works as both debit and credit, from [credit-card](/questions/tagged/credit-card) in the question tags.

Yes, [PayPal can transfer funds into your credit card](http://pages.ebay.com.sg/sea/paypal/withdraw.html) balance.

> We’re pleased to announce the launch of a new withdrawal feature, allowing you to transfer funds from your PayPal account to your Visa® branded credit, debit or prepaid card. This new feature will enable you to gain convenient access to your funds and is available in 26 countries, including Malaysia, India, Indonesia and the Philippines.

You have to check that:

- Your country is listed for this feature.
- Your card is a Visa® - It may work with other cards too. YMMV
- Your bank is OK with that.

  > **Q: Will every Visa® credit, debit or prepaid card work?**
  >   A:    No. Eligibility to withdraw funds to a Visa® credit/debit card may vary based on the issuing banks guidelines and regulations.
- You respect the limits on the transfer amount.
- You are ok with a USD $5.00 (or local currency equivalent) fee, plus currency exchange fees.

I have used this feature in the past and transfered funds from paypal to my credit card. The money did not end up in my bank account, but "paid off" some of my credit card expenses.